# Ignore img tags in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-replace

I want to replace a word in an HTML string, but I want to exclude the replacement if the word was in the attributes of the 'img' element.

Example:

```
$word = 'google';
$html = 'I like google and here is its logo <img src="images/google.png" alt="Image of google logo" />';

$replacement = '<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>';
$result =  preg_replace('/\s'.($word).'/u', $replacement, $html);
```

preg_replace will also replace the "google" words inside 'src' and 'alt' attributes, I want it to just replace the word outside the 'img' element.

Comment: What you ask is impossible to be done in a reliable manner. Regular expressions are a wonderful tool, but not for every task out there. You want to use a DOM parser for such task.

Comment: @arkascha Seems like it's possible with regex! http://stackoverflow.com/a/29580308/3933332

Comment: @Rizier123 I never claimed it is impossible, did I? The problem with such approaches is that you will never get a reliable solution. You will always find more cases where it does not work as expected and where you have to fix it again and again.

Comment: @arkascha could you please provide a simple code to do this using the DOM parser?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the discard pattern. For instance you can use a regex like this:

```
<.*?google.*?\/>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|google
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qW8iA5/1)**

[image]

The idea behind this pattern is to discard the `google` word inside `<` and `>` but keep the rest:

```
<.*?google.*?\/>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)  --> This part will skip the matches where google is within <...>
|google                         --> but will keep the others google
```

You can add many "discard" pattern you want, like:

```
discard patt1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|discard patt(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|...(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|keep this
```

Comment: Thanks @Fede can I just ignore the 'img' and 'a' elements?

Comment: @WaseemAbuSenjer yes, you can use this regex `<(img|a).*?google.*?\/>(*SKIP)(*F)|google` https://regex101.com/r/oM3qQ4/2

Answer (score 0):

Use positive lookahead `(?=.*?<.*?/>)`

```
$html = 'I like google and here is its logo <img src="images/google.png" alt="Image of google logo" />';

$result = preg_replace('%(?=.*?<.*?/>)google%im', 'ANOTHER WORD', $html);
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/lCbBCp)</kbd>

**EXPLANATION**:

```
(?=.*?<.*?/>)google
-------------------

Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=.*?<.*?/>)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match the character “<” literally «<»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match the character string “/>” literally «/>»
Match the character string “google” literally (case insensitive) «google»

ANOTHER WORD

Insert the character string “ANOTHER WORD” literally «ANOTHER WORD»
```

More info about [Regex Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)