# PHP Regex to capture/replace text not located within an HTML element

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently attempting to use a regular expression to automatically capture, replace & link text located within a larger body of content. I'm able to do this fine to a certain degree. My issue comes when the text I am looking for, is already located within a link.

Here is the current code I have:

```
foreach( $items as $item ) {
    if( !empty($item->generic_url) ) {

        $search = $item->title;
        $url = $item->generic_url;
        $content = preg_replace("/($search)/i", "<a href=\"$url\">$1</a>", $content, 1);

    }
}
```

**Scenario A** ( it SHOULD auto-link first occurrence of "link" ):

```
$content = "This is some text that will link to another page";
```

**Scenario B** ( it SHOULD NOT auto-link first occurrence of "link" ):

```
$content = "This is some text that will <a href='#'>link</a> to another page";
```

**Scenario C** ( it SHOULD NOT auto-link first occurrence of "link" ):

```
$content = "This is some text that <a href='#'>will link to</a> another page";
```

Comment: It will work not everytime - `/(\blink\b)(?![^<]*<\/a)/` - https://regex101.com/r/FwAeIP/1

Comment: Thanks for the word boundary idea splash58.  I ended up using that in my final answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out based on this question/answer:
[Ignore img tags in preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29580025/ignore-img-tags-in-preg-replace#answers)

To achieve my specific goal, I used the following code:

```
$content = preg_replace("/<a.*?\/a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b($search)\b/i", "<a href="$url">$1</a>", $content, 1);
```

In addition to using the discard pattern, I added a word boundary to ensure there were no partial words that were matched.